# Is there a way to stop a HttpClient's execution in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, httpclient, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that handles a rather long download, using HttpClient. I'd like to stop the execution of this request if the user finishes the Activity that starts it. How can I achieve this?

So I started the AsyncTask, HttpClient is in execute(), processing a GET request, is there a way to terminate this?

Comment: Have you tried to close the stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async task has a cancel call that you could override. You could get at your HttpClient from there and close the stream.

Comment: How?. I can get to my http client, but there's no such method :/

Comment: It wont work. `HttpClient.Execute` blocks the call. `OnCancelled` wont be get called untill HttpClient releases the lock.

Comment: Right, this doesn't work to actually interrupt the request, you need to use abort() as per the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

1. Call `AsyncTask#cancel` to discard pending task
2. according to [HttpClient docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html), use `HttpUriRequest#abort()` to abort http request

> 1.4. Aborting requests
>
> In some situations HTTP request execution fails to complete within the expected time frame due to high load on the target server or too many concurrent requests issued on the client side. In such cases it may be necessary to terminate the request prematurely and unblock the execution thread blocked in a I/O operation. HTTP requests being executed by HttpClient can be aborted at any stage of execution by invoking HttpUriRequest#abort() method. This method is thread-safe and can be called from any thread. When an HTTP request is aborted its execution thread - even if currently blocked in an I/O operation - is guaranteed to unblock by throwing a InterruptedIOException